# How have I got Two identical iCloud accounts?

Tags: icloud, user-account

When I look in Internet Accounts, I have two identical iCloud accounts. How can I get rid of 1 of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete both - it will let you know if any data needs to sync up and then you can sign in again.

Sometimes the system loses track of a preference, so I recommend a back up of your local data and then perhaps restarting / disk check to be sure the storage is healthy before adding the account and re-syncing data.

Comment: It won’t let me delete them?

Comment: Can you back up and then erase the device entirely? If not, vendor support might be needed to look at things on the server side.

Comment: Called Apple. They talked me through deleting a whole lot of User folders. Got it back to a workable state then everything came back from iCloud, and after a few password updates all is now working again. Took about 90 minutes once the problem was escalated from my first  responder who tried his best. Basically everything i’d already done, then an engineer came on and we fixed it. They didn’t know either how I’d ended up with duplicate accounts. But the engineer certainly recorded it.

Comment: Excellent @HarryMcGovern. I wasn’t even sure if your accounts were on Apple TV or iOS or macOS. Glad they sorted it!